# Lazy Loading Exception: System is not defined

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am running angular 2.2.4 following the instructions [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/). This uses webpack similar to how the angular CLI works, but there are differences. I am attempting to lazy load some modules, but it isn't working.

In my app.routing.ts, I have:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

...

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: './components/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
    },
    ...
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

In my lazy.routing.ts, I have:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LazyComponent } from '../lazy/lazy.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LazyComponent
    }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

In my lazy.module.ts, I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';
import { routing } from './lazy.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [routing],
    declarations: [LazyComponent]
})

export class LazyModule { }
```

And I get this error:

"EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined
ReferenceError: System is not defined"

The exact same process works in the CLI, but not with the project structure I'm using, so I'm guessing I'm missing some dependency or configuration that's already set up in the CLI.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. I haven't looked at this the past two months. If I find anything, I'll report back.

Comment: I know this may be a long shot, but I updated a Angular application from Angular 9 to 12. And although I added the new way of implementing lazy loaded modules one module wasn't loading and giving this error. Turns out I had to uninstall npm package: uuidv4 and install uuid. Something was hanging in the old one.